# Django mocks not working as expected

Tags: python, django, mocking, django-testing, python-mock

I'm struggling with django mock; I have even simplified an unit test but the test is still failing. I want to verify that a method is called (even with any parameter), but the "assert_called_once_with" always returns False.
Currently I'm trying:

```
@patch('utils.make_reset_password')
def test_shouldHaveCalledMakeResetToken(self, mocked):
    user = User.get(...)
    make_reset_password(user)
    mocked.assert_called_once_with(user)
```

Even this simple example is failing with:

```
AssertionError: Expected 'make_reset_password' to be called once. Called 0 times
```

How this is possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You call `make_reset_password` in the test itself so why do you want to mock it?

Comment: As I said, I have simplified the test. This is not what I want to test, but I was allways getting "called 0 times" error, so I simplified it by calling the method on the test... and the "called 0 times" error has not changed

Comment: Can you update the question with the code yo want to test?

Comment: I want to ensure that, given an API call, the mocked method is called. So I was doing the test call with the APIClient, but I was getting the error I explained. So I have simplified the test, but even when I'm calling the mocked method in the test, the test keep saying that it has not been called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use full path to `utils`, e.g. `@patch('my_app.utils.make_reset_password')` and then in the test call a function that calls `make_reset_password`.

```
@patch('my_app.utils.make_reset_password')
def test_shouldHaveCalledMakeResetToken(self, mock_make_reset_password):
    user = User.get(...)
    function_under_test(user)
    mock_make_reset_password.assert_called_once_with(user)
```

**EDIT**

The other thing that comes to my mind is you are not mocking the correct function. If `make_reset_password` is imported from `utils` in another module then you need to change the path in the `@patch` decorator.

For example

```
# my_module.py
from my_app.utils import make_reset_password

def run_make_reset_password(user):
    make_reset_password(user)


# tests.py
@patch('my_app.my_module.make_reset_password')
def test_shouldHaveCalledMakeResetToken(self, mock_make_reset_password):
    user = User.get(...)
    run_make_reset_password(user)
    mock_make_reset_password.assert_called_once_with(user)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it's working fine, the issue was with the path I was using on the @patch method; using the way you explained in your example has solved my issue. Thanks so much!